# Errors with Google Maps Android API V2 and Android 2.3.5

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, android-2.3-gingerbread, supportmapfragment

I am trying to use SupportMapFragment class with the Google Maps API v2.
But I keep running into this error.
I have imported the google-play-services_lib project, and added it to my Java
Build Path.

```
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yo/com.example.yo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:250)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1712)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at com.example.yo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    ... 11 more
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060000
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:901)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:826)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:808)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at maps.af.w.a(Unknown Source)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at maps.z.ab.a(Unknown Source)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at maps.z.ag.a(Unknown Source)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at maps.z.ag.a(Unknown Source)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at maps.z.bw.a(Unknown Source)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at maps.z.r.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IMapFragmentDelegate.java:107)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.e$4.a(Unknown Source)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.a(Unknown Source)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
    03-29 23:58:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(26163):    ... 20 more
    03-29 23:58:09.933: D/dalvikvm(26163): GC_CONCURRENT freed 367K, 45% free 3282K/5959K, external 0K/0K, paused 6ms+5ms
    03-29 23:58:11.764: I/Process(26163): Sending signal. PID: 26163 SIG: 9
```

Here's my Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.yo"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

         <permission
                android:name="com.example.yo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature">
         </permission>

        <uses-permission
            android:name="com.example.yo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
        <uses-permission
            android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/> 

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.yo.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
             <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="the key"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

My MainActivity:

```
    package com.example.yo;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
```

And the XML:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: "I have imported the google-play-services_lib project, and added it to my Java Build Path." -- if you messed with your build path manually, then you did not add the google-play-services_lib project to your hosting project correctly.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I did the following: Project > Properties > Android > Add > google-play-services_lib
Since it didn't fix the issue, I also added the project to the Java Build Path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line of code from manifast file:

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

it's not needed for google maps API V2.

And it's not related to your current problem but you need to add the following permissions as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and you need to add the google library in other way, read more about it in a blog post I wrote:

[Google Map API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: I added these permissions, and I'm reading your post right now, thanks :-)

Comment: Okay, fixed the permissions, and added the support library by right-click > Android Tools > Add Support Library. No luck still, but now I see 
        
        03-30 00:30:31.192: E/dalvikvm(26660): Could not find class 'maps.i.k', referenced from method maps.z.ag.a
        
Before the big error

Comment: and what do you see in your application? this error is usual related to API key problems. please try to generate a new key and register it via the API Console.

Comment: I did that, unfortunaltely it fails with the same error. 

    03-30 00:51:27.198: E/AndroidRuntime(26822): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060000

I believe it has something to do with this, but I can't really figure it out..

Comment: it's the same error you had at first time... you are back to the original problem... so you did some thing wrong. go over all the steps of the guide again. see where your mistake is.

Comment: @czardoz Did you get a solution? I'm with the same problem :(((